# how to access the variable from another php file

Tags: php, variables

I have an array in one `php1` file which I want to access in another `php2`  file but if i use either include or require once am also getting the output of the `php1` file. I want to access only the variables from `php1` but not the output. Can anyone suggest how to do that. In `php1` I have lot of menus and boxes which I don't want to include in `php2` except the variables.

```
<?
session_start();
require_once('home.php');
if($_GET["reset"]==1)
{
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

if i use this am getting all the output from the `home.php` page. I want only the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the variables on the home page to be accessible via a function or better still, make them session variables

Comment: is there some way without using function or session to access the variables.

Comment: Yea, post them to the new page probably using $_GET

Answer (score 0):

> is there some way without using function or session to access the variables

As per your request. A simple skeleton to show you how it is done.

We pass the variable `$myVar` through the URL and use `$_GET` in the next page to use it. We use [`htmlspecialchars();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to clean user input.

We use the `if (isset($_GET['myVar']))` so it doesn't throw *Notice: Undefined index error*.

**pageOne.php**

```
<?php   
$myVar = "My variable one.";

echo "<a href='pageTwo.php?myVar=" . $myVar . "'>Page Two</a>"
?>
```

**pageTwo.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['myVar'])) {
    $myVar = htmlspecialchars($_GET['myVar'], ENT_QUOTES);

    // Now you can use $myVar.
}
?>
```